# reduce the white space before and after new

Tags: formatting

How do I reduce the white space before and after the `\begin{mq} … \end{mq}` block in the following code?  Ideally, I would like the white space between the environment and the preceding and succeeding paragraphs to be 1em. The same as between paragraphs outside the environment block.

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}

% Page Setup
\usepackage[paperheight=8in,
            paperwidth=6in,
            top=.1in,
            bottom=.2in,
            right=.1in,
            left=.1in,
            heightrounded]{geometry} 

% Set space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

% Custom Quotation Environment
\newenvironment {mq} %My Quote
{
    \ignorespaces
    \begin{list}{}
    {
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1cm}
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{1cm}
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    }        
    \item % Inserted text 
}
{\end{list} \par \ignorespacesafterend}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{mq}
    Average wage of employees \dotfill\ $\$\,2,200$\\
    Average salary and profit of owners \dotfill\ $\$\,26,000$\\
\end{mq}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should take a look at `enumitem` which makes customising lists and defining custom lists easy (well, easier).

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}

% Page Setup
\usepackage[paperheight=8in,
            paperwidth=6in,
            top=.1in,
            bottom=.2in,
            right=.1in,
            left=.1in,
            heightrounded]{geometry} 

% Set space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

% Custom Quotation Environment
\newenvironment {mq} %My Quote
{%
    %\ignorespaces
    \begin{list}{}%
    {%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1cm}%
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{1cm}%
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\setlength\partopsep{0em}%
\setlength\parsep{0pt}%
\setlength\topsep{0pt}%
\setlength\itemsep{0pt}%
    }       
    \item\relax % Inserted text 
}
{\end{list}%
 \ignorespacesafterend}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{mq}
    Average wage of employees \dotfill\ $\$\,2,200$\\
    Average salary and profit of owners \dotfill\ $\$\,26,000$%\\
\end{mq}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setlength\partopsep{0em}` and `\setlength\topsep{0pt}` fix the white space before the environment, but there is still too much white space after the environment. 

`\relax`, `\parsep` and `\itemsep` don't seem to affect either the white space before or after the environment. 

The Whitespace after the environment appears to be a double instead of single space.

Answer (score 1):

Use the proper tools.

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}

% Page Setup
\usepackage[paperheight=8in,
            paperwidth=6in,
            top=.1in,
            bottom=.2in,
            right=.1in,
            left=.1in,
            heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Set space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

% Custom Quotation Environment
\newenvironment {mq} %My Quote
 {\partopsep=0pt \adjustwidth{1cm}{1cm}}
 {\endadjustwidth}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-3]
\begin{mq}
    Average wage of employees \dotfill\ $\$\,2{,}200$\\
    Average salary and profit of owners \dotfill\ $\$\,26{,}000$
\end{mq}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]